# What is the usual Allocation unit for a process on Linux?

Tags: memory, linux-kernel

I'm currently studying memory management in Operating Systems.

Allocation Unit is the smallest unit of memory the OS will give to any process.

I've read in [this page](http://blog.zhangxianwei.com/?p=692), in the 'Memory allocation inside kernel' section, that a page is the smallest unit an OS will give to a process.

But in [this page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Operating_System_Design/Memory_Management), in the 'Allocated memory' section, it says the OS can divide it into much smaller chunks (6 bytes for example) and give it to the application when requested.

I'm not sure if both links are talking about the same thing, but my question is: What is the usual Allocation Unit in an Operating System with Virtual Memory and Paging?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your second reference, where it says

> The memory allocator gets a big chunk of memory (say, 4 pages, or 4 * 4 KiB) and divides this into much smaller chunks

"the memory allocator" is not the kernel but the libc routines like malloc.

The kernel allocates memory *to the process* in page-sized chunks. malloc keeps track of used and unused portions of those pages as the application requests them and frees them.